# Changing orientation of 3D dataset in MATLAB (worked in ImageJ/Fiji)

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure, imagej

I have a 3D dataset (375x91x223) called 'vol' which is a collection of 2D images. If I visualise 'vol' (using a software called imageJ) it is in the Y-Z plane:

[image: Image 1]

Within imageJ I can change the orientation to the X-Y plane to look like:

[image: Image 2]

which so happens to be 375x223x91 dataset.

I want to achieve the same thing in MATLAB so after importing 'vol' in the Y-Z plane, I use:

```
vol = permute(vol,[1 3 2]);
```

This changes the data from: 375x91x223 to 375x223x91

However the output is [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N00f.png) (after exporting the data and re-opening in imageJ). The collection of images in Image 3 are in the reverse order of Image 2 (i.e. same image is on slice 70/91 in Image 2 and 23/91 in Image 3). Any help of resolving this in MATLAB will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can invert the z axis of your data set, e.g. in Matlab:

```
vol = vol(:,:,end:-1:1)
```

or in ImageJ using *Image > Stacks > Tools > Reverse*

Comment: Alternately, `flip(vol, 3)`

Comment: Thank you for your help!